# Is there an alternative to setting the endKey of the ngxDaterangepicker?

Tags: angular, user-interface

Setting the endKey of the ngxDaterangepicker does not show the end date of the daterangepicker.

startDate and EndDate has also been set. Also tried setting startDate and endDate in ngOnInit and ngOnChanges. Also tried not setting locale.

Value on debugging is showing different start date and end date in selected. Result is startKey is correct but endKey is incorrect in html page.

Comment: Post you code or add  a stackbitz demo to your question

Comment: <input type="text" id="daterange" readonly="readonly" matInput ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="selected" [minDate]="minDate"
             startKey="start" endKey="end" [locale]="locale" 
             class="form-control" (close)="onDateChange()" [ngClass]="{'input-error':sameDateError}"/>

Answer (score 0):

So set the Startkey and Endkey, your model must contain the start and end key value as correct Date or moment object.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';
import {Moment} from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  selected: {'start': Moment, 'end': Moment} = {
    'start': moment('2019-07-05'),
    'end': moment('2019-07-10')
  };
  minDate = moment('2019-07-01');
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd 
readonly
[locale]="{applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}"
[(ngModel)]="selected"  
[minDate]="minDate" 
startKey="start" 
endKey="end" 
class="form-control"
/>
```